# hittesting on Listitems in a Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I customized a Listbox to show a Pie-Chart (each Listitem is one slice of the Pie). To do this i used an Itemtemplate which (for now) only consists of a `Shape`. To make those shapes form a full circle, i calculated start/endangle for each piece and used a custom `ItemsPanelTemplate` to stack the Items on top of each other.

When I click anywhere near the Pie, the "last" item gets selected since it is located on top of the others. This is quite obvious, but I hoped since the ItemTemplate only contains a `Shape`, it would inherit the hit-testing from there and not assume that all items are represented by rectangles.

Where am I supposed to include the hittesting? I would like to set `IsHitTestVisible="false"` to everything inside my `ItemTemplate`, except for the shape - but since it doesn't actually contain anything except for my shape, i am stuck right now.

**Edit:**

I tried surrounding my `Shape` with a Grid with transparent background, on which i did set `IsHitTestVisible="false"`. This still results in selecting the last element on each click while i would've assumed that nothing would be selected. I think i might be confused about how hittesting is supposed to work?

**Code:**

Since i am new to WPF i might have missed something during the implementation. I added the relevant codeparts of a minimal example:

**My `Shape`-class:**

```
public class PiePiece : Shape
{
    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get { return GetPieGeometry() }
    }

    //some DependencyProperties and helper methods.

    private Geometry GetPieGeometry()
    {
        //calculations
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window [...] xmlns:Runner="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
<Window.Resources>

    <!-- some custom converters -->

    <!-- ListBox-Style with the custom ControlTemplate for my Listbox -->

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemPanel">
        <Grid/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox [...] ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemPanel}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <Runner:PiePiece IsHitTestVisible="False" [...]>
                <!-- Dependency Properties are set via Multibinding here -->
            </Runner:PiePiece>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

</Window>
```

Comment: I would have thought your solution should work, but try an {x:null} background rather than transparent.

Comment: Every item in a `ListBox` is an instance of [ListBoxItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750821.aspx) with a `ContentPresenter` inside it. Try attaching [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com) to your application and using its Events tab to see where your mouse click is going, and use the Properties tab to inspect your visual tree's hit testing related properties. It may help you track down what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason why the hittesting did not work as desired:

The default template for the ListBoxItem-Style surrounds the `ContentPresenter` with a `Border` with transparent background. All click-events were caught and handled by that border, instead of my `ContentPresenter`. Writing my own style for the ListBoxItem and setting the Background to `{x:null}` as suggested by Gaz fixed the problem (as did removing the border, but I added another one by now for further customizations).